# stdlib.h alternative in Linux kernel?

Tags: c, linux, kernel

When developing a kernel module in Linux, using the C standard library isn't allowed.
However, in case I need to use some common functionality like `strcat()`, where do I need to go to?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whatever is not implemented in the Linux kernel, you have to implement yourself or borrow from another open source kernel module.  However, you'll find that `strcat` is implemented in the kernel.

See the [kernel API](http://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/) documentation.  Specifically the [Basic C Library Functions](http://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/libc.html) section for your general question, and the [String Manipulation](http://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/ch02s02.html) section for your specific question about `strcat`.

You'll want to include `linux/string.h`.

I don't know why the kernel API documentation doesn't actually show the header file that you have to include to get the function.  But if you're looking for something, you can restrict your search to `/include/linux` because that is where header files go if they have functions that are shared amongst different parts of the kernel.

Header files outside `/include/linux` contain definitions only for source files residing in the same directory as the header.  The exception is `/arch/.../include`, which will contain architecture-specific headers instead of platform independent ones.

Comment: Is there a list of the header files in which these kind of functions are kept? (like you've mentioned 'linux\string.h')

Comment: @Fairview:  Not that I could find, which is odd.  I guess you'll have to find the function you want in the kernel API and then search for it in `/include/linux`.  I added more detail in my answer about header files in the kernel and why you can restrict your search to `/include/linux` and its subdirectories.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry @eq - thinking of another function.

Why not

```
void (char *d, const char *s);
{
   if (*d)
   { 
       for (; *d; ++d) {} ;
      --d;
   }
   strcpy(d, s);
}
```

I could do `strcpy` if you wish

Comment: @indiv - Oops the thinking is right. Those functions can be acheived eaily.

Comment: Are we all happy how - despite that that a string function requires a library?!

Comment: ... And is the Linux kernel written in C?

Comment: @indiv - You figure it out. The point is that the kernel is written in C and therefore the original questioner can write it for himself.

Comment: @indiv - I was trying to make a point that fairview is incorrect that a kernel model in C is difficult to reconstruct so with those libraries. Yes the code was wrong but I wrote it off the hoof. But here is 9pm and We (my boyfriend, my other myfriend (the pouch) and myself need to have a some food!)

Comment: I'm pretty sure strlen in kernel is more optimized than this.

Comment: @Ablm - Probably writting in aseemebly language and optimized for the particular processor.

Comment: yeah, we should find lot of fun there... but not my cup of tea! just a good reason to re-use it ;-)