# Conflicting types fd_set

Tags: c, linux

In my program I'm using 
`stdlib.h` which includes `sys/types.h` which includes `sys/select.h` which defines `typedef struct fd_set`.

I also include `linux/spi/spidev.h` which includes `linux/types.h` which defines `typedef __kernel_fd_set fd_set`.

So those names `fd_set` collide and the program can't be compiled. What is the best way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you know which kernel version the /usr/include/linux contents are based on? This can be found out from the version of the package that installed /usr/include/linux/types.h for example.

Answer (score 2):

When developing a kernel module in Linux, using the C standard library (e.g. `stdlib.h`) isn't allowed. Please, refer to [stdlib.h alternative in Linux kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011075/stdlib-h-alternative-in-linux-kernel)

Comment: I'm not developing a kernel module tho.

Comment: @octavio __kernel_fd_set is dedicated for kernel module development. I think, including linux/spi/spidev.h means SPI driver/kernel module development.
If you look inside this header, you will see the following:
#include <linux/types.h>
* User space versions of kernel symbols for SPI clocking modes,  matching <linux/spi/spi.h> */ and so on

Comment: I need to include spidev.h for the ioctl-macros. Check out spidev_test.c, it is a userspace program which includes it as well and makes use of the macros to setup the spidev via ioctl-calls. That program is including both spidev.h and stdlib.h without problems.

Comment: @octavio Can you compile spidev_test.c successfully on your system, or do you get the same fd_set conflict?